# Show or Display Text of the Selected Radio Button in Email and Hide Others

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to figure how to make the code shown in the email the options of the selected radio button. I have 5 radio button and if I select on the radio it shows their option but when I go to submit the request it send all the data from all other options

Also trying to make the the code work in the PHP format

```js
$(function() {

    // listen for changes
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){

        // get checked one
        var $target = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        // hide all divs with .showhide class
        $(".showhide").hide();
        // show div that corresponds to selected radio.
        $( $target.attr('data-section') ).show();

    // trigger the change on page load
    }).trigger('change');

});
```

```css
html, body {
            min-height: 100%;
            }
            body, div, form, input, select, textarea, p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            outline: none;
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #666;
            line-height: 22px;
            }
            h1 {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 32px;
            color: #fff;
            z-index: 2;
            }
            legend {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #095484;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            }
            h5 {
            margin: 10px 0;
            }
            .testbox {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: inherit;
            padding: 20px;
            }
            form {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #095484;
            }
            .banner {
            position: relative;
            height: 210px;
            background-image: url("//pww-wwdweb01/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/Krishneel/OnBoarding/Walgreen.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            }
            .banner::after {
            content: "";
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            }
            input, select, textarea {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            }
            input {
            width: calc(100% - 10px);
            padding: 5px;
            }
            select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 7px 0;
            background: transparent;
            }
            textarea {
            width: calc(100% - 12px);
            padding: 5px;
            }
            .item:hover p, .item:hover i, .question:hover p, .question label:hover, input:hover::placeholder, a {
            color: #095484;
            }
            .item input:hover, .item select:hover, .item textarea:hover {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 #095484;
            color: #095484;
            }

            input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
            display: none;
            }
            .showhide {
            display:none;
            }
            .item i, input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #a9a9a9;
            }
            .item i {
            right: 2%;
            top: 30px;
            z-index: 1;
            }
            [type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            right: 1%;
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]  {
            display: none;
            }
            label.radio, label.check {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px 20px 15px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            .question span {
            margin-left: 30px;
            }
            span.required {
            margin-left: 0;
            color: red;
            }
            .checkbox-item label {
            margin: 5px 20px 10px 0;
            }
            label.radio:before, label.check:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            }
            label.radio:before {
            width: 17px;
            height: 17px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid #095484;
            }
            label.check:before {
            top: 2px;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #095484;
            }
            input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check:before {
            background: #095484;
            }
            label.radio:after {
            left: 5px;
            border: 3px solid #095484;
            }
            label.check:after {
            left: 4px;
            border: 3px solid #fff;
            }
            label.radio:after, label.check:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 6px;
            width: 8px;
            height: 4px;
            background: transparent;
            border-top: none;
            border-right: none;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            opacity: 0;
            }
            input[type=radio]:checked + label:after, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
            opacity: 1;
            }
            .btn-block {
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            }
            button {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #095484;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            button:hover {
            background: #0666a3;
            }
            @media (min-width: 568px) {
            .city-item {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            }
            .city-item input {
            width: calc(50% - 20px);
            }
            .city-item select {
            width: calc(50% - 8px);
            }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testbox">
            <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <div class="banner">
                    <h1>Employment Form</h1>
                </div><br>
                <p>Please fill out with the information that is requested below and submit the employment verification form. Thank you!</p>
                <br>
                <div class="question">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Status</legend>
                        <p>Choose Employee Status:<span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <div class="question-answer">
                            <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_1" name="investigator" data-section="#div-1" />
                            <label for="radio_1" class="radio"><span>New Hire</span></label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_2" name="investigator" data-section="#div-2" />
                            <label for="radio_2" class="radio"><span>Upgrade Credentials to DCS</span></label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_3" name="investigator" data-section="#div-3">
                            <label for="radio_3" class="radio"><span>Return to Work</span></label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_4" name="investigator" data-section="#div-4" >
                            <label for="radio_4" class="radio"><span>Terminate Access DCS or Above</span></label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_5" name="investigator" data-section="#div-5" >
                            <label for="radio_5" class="radio"><span>Terminate Access TM AS400</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!---New Hire Option -->
                <div class="showhide" id="div-1">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <p>Date</p>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
                        <p>Department</p>
                        <select>
                            <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
                            <option value="1">HR</option>
                            <option value="2">AP</option>
                            <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
                            <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
                            <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
                            <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
                            <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
                            <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
                            <option value="9">IO</option>
                            <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
                            <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
                            <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
                            <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>User On-Boarding Notification Info:</p>
                        <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br>
                    <div class="question">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
                        <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
                        <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
                                <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
                                <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
                                <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
                                <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
                                <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
                        <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!---Upgrade Creditials Option -->
                <div class="showhide" id="div-2">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <p>Date</p>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
                        <br>
                        <p>Department</p>
                        <select>
                            <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
                            <option value="1">HR</option>
                            <option value="2">AP</option>
                            <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
                            <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
                            <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
                            <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
                            <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
                            <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
                            <option value="9">IO</option>
                            <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
                            <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
                            <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
                            <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
                        <div class="question">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
                            <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
                            <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!---Return to Work Option -->
                <div class="showhide" id="div-3">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <p>Department</p>
                        <select>
                            <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
                            <option value="1">HR</option>
                            <option value="2">AP</option>
                            <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
                            <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
                            <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
                            <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
                            <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
                            <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
                            <option value="9">IO</option>
                            <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
                            <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
                            <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
                            <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
                        <div class="question">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
                            <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
                            <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
                                    <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                 <!---Terminate DCS or I/O Option -->
                 <div class="showhide" id="div-4">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                        <label for="text_3" class="text">Enter I/O or DCS Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_3" placeholder="Enter I/O or DCS Full Name" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <p>Termination Date:</p>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
                        <br>
                        <p>Department</p>
                        <select>
                            <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
                            <option value="1">HR</option>
                            <option value="2">AP</option>
                            <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
                            <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
                            <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
                            <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
                            <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
                            <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
                            <option value="9">IO</option>
                            <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
                            <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
                            <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
                            <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                 <!---Terminate TM Option -->
                <div class="showhide" id="div-5">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                        <label for="text_4" class="text">Enter TM Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_4" placeholder="Enter TM Full Name" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
                        <br>
                        <p>Termination Date:</p>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>DCS Approved</legend>
                            <label for="text_7" class="text">Enter DCS Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_7" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
                            <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="btn-block">
                    <button type="submit" href="/">Submit Your Request</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to actually remove the elements that are hidden from the DOM before you submit:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
   $(this).children(':hidden').remove();
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    $(this).children(':hidden').remove();
  });

  // listen for changes
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

    // get checked one
    var $target = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    // hide all divs with .showhide class
    $(".showhide").hide();
    // show div that corresponds to selected radio.
    $($target.attr('data-section')).show();

    // trigger the change on page load
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body,
div,
form,
input,
select,
textarea,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 22px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

legend {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #095484;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h5 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.testbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #095484;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 210px;
  background-image: url("//pww-wwdweb01/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/Krishneel/OnBoarding/Walgreen.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 0;
  background: transparent;
}

textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  padding: 5px;
}

.item:hover p,
.item:hover i,
.question:hover p,
.question label:hover,
input:hover::placeholder,
a {
  color: #095484;
}

.item input:hover,
.item select:hover,
.item textarea:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 #095484;
  color: #095484;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}

.showhide {
  display: none;
}

.item i,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

.item i {
  right: 2%;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  right: 1%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label.radio,
label.check {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 20px 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.question span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

span.required {
  margin-left: 0;
  color: red;
}

.checkbox-item label {
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 0;
}

label.radio:before,
label.check:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

label.radio:before {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #095484;
}

label.check:before {
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #095484;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.check:before {
  background: #095484;
}

label.radio:after {
  left: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #095484;
}

label.check:after {
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

label.radio:after,
label.check:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label:after,
input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #095484;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #0666a3;
}

@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .city-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .city-item input {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  .city-item select {
    width: calc(50% - 8px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testbox">
  <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1>Employment Form</h1>
    </div><br>
    <p>Please fill out with the information that is requested below and submit the employment verification form. Thank you!</p>
    <br>
    <div class="question">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Status</legend>
        <p>Choose Employee Status:<span class="required">*</span></p>
        <div class="question-answer">
          <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_1" name="investigator" data-section="#div-1" />
          <label for="radio_1" class="radio"><span>New Hire</span></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_2" name="investigator" data-section="#div-2" />
          <label for="radio_2" class="radio"><span>Upgrade Credentials to DCS</span></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_3" name="investigator" data-section="#div-3">
          <label for="radio_3" class="radio"><span>Return to Work</span></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_4" name="investigator" data-section="#div-4">
          <label for="radio_4" class="radio"><span>Terminate Access DCS or Above</span></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" value="none" id="radio_5" name="investigator" data-section="#div-5">
          <label for="radio_5" class="radio"><span>Terminate Access TM AS400</span></label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!---New Hire Option -->
    <div class="showhide" id="div-1">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
        <br>
        <p>Date</p>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
        <p>Department</p>
        <select>
          <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
          <option value="1">HR</option>
          <option value="2">AP</option>
          <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
          <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
          <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
          <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
          <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
          <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
          <option value="9">IO</option>
          <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
          <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
          <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
          <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
        </select>
        <p>User On-Boarding Notification Info:</p>
        <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <div class="question">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
          <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
          <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
              <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
              <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
              <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
              <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
              <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <br>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
        <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!---Upgrade Creditials Option -->
    <div class="showhide" id="div-2">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
        <br>
        <p>Date</p>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
        <br>
        <p>Department</p>
        <select>
          <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
          <option value="1">HR</option>
          <option value="2">AP</option>
          <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
          <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
          <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
          <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
          <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
          <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
          <option value="9">IO</option>
          <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
          <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
          <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
          <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <div class="question">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
            <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
            <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!---Return to Work Option -->
    <div class="showhide" id="div-3">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
        <label for="text_1" class="text">Enter Employee Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_1" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
        <br>
        <p>Department</p>
        <select>
          <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
          <option value="1">HR</option>
          <option value="2">AP</option>
          <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
          <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
          <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
          <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
          <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
          <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
          <option value="9">IO</option>
          <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
          <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
          <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
          <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <div class="question">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Additional Access/Accessories</legend>
            <p>Select All That Apply:</p>
            <div class="question-answer checkbox-item">
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_1" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_1" class="check"><span>Full DCS Access : DC NET, Email Lists, K Drive, AS400, Shared, etcDrive,</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_2" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_2" class="check"><span>Laptop</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_3" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_3" class="check"><span>Phone</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_4" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_4" class="check"><span>Office Space</span></label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="check_5" name="checklist">
                <label for="check_5" class="check"><span>Computer Setup/Verify in Location</span></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!---Terminate DCS or I/O Option -->
    <div class="showhide" id="div-4">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
        <label for="text_3" class="text">Enter I/O or DCS Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_3" placeholder="Enter I/O or DCS Full Name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
        <br>
        <p>Termination Date:</p>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
        <br>
        <p>Department</p>
        <select>
          <option selected value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
          <option value="1">HR</option>
          <option value="2">AP</option>
          <option value="3">SC-AM</option>
          <option value="4">SC-PM</option>
          <option value="5">FC-AM</option>
          <option value="6">FC-PM</option>
          <option value="7">INB-AM</option>
          <option value="8">INB-PM</option>
          <option value="9">IO</option>
          <option value="10">Maintenace</option>
          <option value="11">Shipping-AM</option>
          <option value="12">sHIPPING-PM</option>
          <option value="13">Computer Room</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>I/O or Manager Approved</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Enter I/O or Manager Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!---Terminate TM Option -->
    <div class="showhide" id="div-5">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Information</legend>
        <label for="text_4" class="text">Enter TM Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_4" placeholder="Enter TM Full Name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="text_2" class="text">One ID & Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="text_2" placeholder="Enter One ID & Employee ID" name="name">
        <br>
        <p>Termination Date:</p>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdate">
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>DCS Approved</legend>
          <label for="text_7" class="text">Enter DCS Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_7" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="name">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Additional Comments</legend>
          <label for="text_6" class="text">Please briefly describe your concern:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" id="text_6" placeholder="Enter Additional Comments Here" name="name">
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-block">
      <button type="submit" href="/">Submit Your Request</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your awesome and a lifesaver. I was going through all the methods I could find online. Right now when I click submit all data goes to email in a simple form.  Now I have to figure it out to make all data go in the table format i created.

Comment: Here is the table i want all the data go to when the user clicks submit button, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hleWFuzVqEQvnypQNYvvhwGxDTl4Tzkk/view?usp=sharing